# Trying to open an activity if an if statement is true

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sudoku

I am working on the Hello Android book Sudoku example and would like to create a congratulations dialog when the game is finished. In a game class I check if there are any blank squares and then in the `PuzzleView` class I am trying to check if the game is solved. If the game is complete it should show the message but I am getting an error when I create the intent.

The constructor `Intent(PuzzleView, Class<Congratulations>)` is undefined.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{

  if (game.isSolved()== true)
  {

     Intent i = new Intent(PuzzleView.this, Congratulations.class);
     startActivity(i); 
  }
  else
  {
     Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event="
     + event);
     /*MORE CODE GOES HERE*/
```

Can anyone help please?
EDIT:- I think the main problem that I am having is trying to startActivity in a class that extends View. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Please check that `PuzzleView` and `Congratulations` classes have **extended Activity**.

**2.** Make sure that you have **defined** those Activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Thought you know it, but still i will show the Intent syntax....

```
Intent i = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, Your_Desired_Activity.class);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your quick response. Congratulations class extends Activity but PuzzleView extends View